# How many arguments are required by transform()?

Tags: c++, stl, transform

The following code has error about the number of arguments for `transform()`. There are two versions of `transform()`, one takes four arguments and another takes five. Why the compiler is trying to use the second version? By the way, I am using VS2008

```
template<class T> T same(const T& t){ return t; }

template<class In, class Out>
Out my_copy(In first, In last, Out res){

    return transform(first, last, res, same);
}

void test(){
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    vector<int> v(a,a+sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));
    vector<int> v2(v.size());
    my_copy(v.begin(), v.end(), v2.begin());
}


// error C2780: '::std::_Enable_if<!std::_Is_checked_iterator<_OutIt>::_Result||!std::_Is_checked_iterator<_OutIt>::_Result,_OutIt>::_Result std::transform(_InIt1,_InIt1,_InIt2,_OutIt,_Fn2)' : expects 5 arguments - 4 provided
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::copy`?

Comment: It's an example from Stroustrup's book, just want to try it.

Comment: The example is wrong then, `same` is not a valid anything.

Answer (score 3):

Because `same` is not a valid `UnaryOperator`, since its a template function. You want something like this instead:

```
&same< typename iterator_traits< Out >::value_type >
```

*Note the `&` is optional*

Or you could make `same` into a polymorphic function object:

```
struct same
{
    template< typename T >
    T operator ()( T const& t ) const { return t; }
};
```

and use `same()` as the `UnaryOperator`.